# SQL Server : Case Statement not execute on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    B.ID
    CASE 
       WHEN (B.NAME <> E.NAME OR (B.NAME IS NULL AND E.NAME IS NOT NULL))
          THEN 'NAME DOES NOT MATCH' 
    END AS NAME_ERROR, 
    B.NAME AS B_NAME, 
    E.NAME AS E_NAME
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE E, BACKUP B
WHERE 
    E.ID = B.ID
```

I am using the above SQL but what I want is that the `NAME_ERROR` column along with `B_NAME` and `E_NAME` should not get select altogether if they match.

Currently, if they match, `B_NAME` & `E_NAME` get selected, along with `NAME_ERROR` column which is populated with null which I don't want.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do with `case` expression you need dynamic SQL Query.

Comment: You might want to take a peek here. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ELSE ''
```

to your CASE expression

Comment: The column itself shouldnt get created

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to do that

Answer (score 0):

you missed an else your query will be

```
SELECT B.ID,
CASE WHEN (B.NAME <> E.NAME OR (B.NAME IS NULL AND E.NAME IS NOT NULL))
THEN 'NAME DOES NOT MATCH' else 'nothing' END AS NAME_ERROR, 
B.NAME AS B_NAME, E.NAME AS E_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E, BACKUP B
WHERE E.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do with `case` expression you need dynamic SQL Query instead you can do :

```
SELECT B.ID, (CASE WHEN (B.NAME <> E.NAME OR (B.NAME IS NULL AND E.NAME IS NOT NULL)
                        )
                   THEN 'NAME DOES NOT MATCH' 
                   ELSE CONCAT (B.NAME, ' ', E.NAME)
              END) AS NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN
     BACKUP B
     ON E.ID = B.ID;
```

However, this doesn't address your actual problem but this is the alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to dynamic SQL is to use an IF:

```
IF someCondition='true'
     SELECT Query A
ELSE
     SELECT Query B
```